# How to drag&drop online images with HTML5?

Tags: image, html, drag-and-drop

I'm currently testing drag & drop. Drag & dropping an image from my desktop works fine, but I'm facing a problem : when I drag & drop an "online" image (from another website, or even from the same webpage using a , the variable `e.dataTransfer.files` is empty.

To sum up what I'm trying to do : You drag an image from your desktop to my page (inside a special zone), then it displays the image inside a `<canvas>`. I'd like to be able to drag an image from my page also, to say something like "Hey, you can first try with these images !".

For the basics of drag & drop, I got inspiration from this tutorial : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because drag&drop online is interpreted as link, not as file transfer. You must first save the picture on your desktop and it will then be intepreted as real drag&drop.
But, since you already have the pictures on your page, you could reach your goal by filling your canvas with your existing images (e.g. using javascript).

P.S.: Drag&Drop works the way you want only if you use 2 different browsers, for example drag a picture from IE into FF. For that you need load your page in 2 different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand better!But how can I get any information from the dropped image (even if I have it on my page and I know the path to that image, I'd like to know "Ok, it's image1 / image2 / image3" who was dropped). As I said `e.dataTransfer.files` is empty.

Comment: If you already have your image on your page you can add an event listener to your image(s), for example onclick, or onmousedown (which is the event when the user pushes the mouse button but has not released it yet). Then you will know WHICH image has been clicked on and you will be able to extract the information from within the DOM structure (like id, src). [**Here**](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp) you can find the new events added to HTML5